# Windows 7 Ultimate back to original Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7, 32-vs-64-bit

Can I downgrade from Windows 7 Ultimate 32 back to Home Premium 64 the one I was originally with and if so how?

Comment: @JakeGould - The proposed duplicate is about downgrading from 64 bit Ultimate to 64 bit Home Premium.  This question is about downgrading from 32 bit Ultimate to 64 bit Home Premium, so the situation isn't strictly the same (e.g., the highest rated answer on that one isn't true for this question).  I'm wondering if the situation is different enough that it isn't a duplicate (or that it might lead to confusion if people don't notice the difference).

Answer (score 2):

**No!** Without clean install, no matter how it is done, you cannot do it.
So either you will have to get windows home Premium disk, or USB or maybe you have partition built in for installation, or recovery. But you will have to do clean install.

**There is no way to change from 32 bit to 64 bit and vice versa without clean install!**

- [What is the difference beetween 32 bit and 64 bit](http://www.howtogeek.com/56701/htg-explains-whats-the-difference-between-32-bit-and-64-bit-windows-7/)
- [There is something more on windows site](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-vista)

(this is not directly related to your question)

> Windows Anytime Upgrade will only allow upgrades from a 32-bit version
>   to a 32-bit version or from a 64-bit version to a 64-bit version. You
>   can't upgrade from a 32-bit version to a 64-bit version with Windows
>   Anytime Upgrade, for example.

You can read about this more on

- [Microsoft windows website](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/videos/upgrade-to-another-edition-of-windows-7-by-using-windows-anytime-upgrade)
- [and on Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Anytime_Upgrade)

Comment: There also isn't a way to go from `Windows 7 Ultimate` to `Windows 7 Home Premium`.  You can of course remove any feature you want that is only available on Ultimate if you want.